# Recreating Regression plot in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to recreate this part of the image with all the labels and brackets (from this [website](https://builtin.com/data-science/adjusted-r-squared))

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}    
\begin{document}     
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={X},
    ylabel={Y},
    xmin=0, xmax=10,
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
    grid=both,
    axis lines=middle,
    every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick}
    ]   
    % Data points
    \addplot+[only marks] coordinates {
    (1, 3.5)
    (2, 5)
    (3, 4)
    (4, 6.3)
    (5, 8)
    (6, 7)
    (7, 9)
    (8, 9.5)
    (9, 12)
    (10, 11)
    };    
    % Regression line
    \addplot[red, domain=0:10, samples=100] { x + 2};
    % Vertical line
    \addplot[blue, dashed] coordinates {
    (5, 8)
    (5, 5.7) };
    %Mean Line
    \addplot[black,dashed]coordinates{
    (0,5.7)
    (10,5.7)   } node [left]{mean};
    % Curly bracket
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt},xshift=3pt,yshift=-5pt](5, 8) -- (5, {5 + 2}) node [midway, below, xshift=7pt] {unexplained variance};
    \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}   
\end{document}
```

I do have the basic structure of the graph, but kinda getting frustrated on the labels and brackets part. I cant get all the labels, annotations straighten out. Also, is there some way to somehow make the graph 'zoomed in' so it can be readable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are after exactly, but the denser your diagram is, the more complicated it naturally gets to position all the labels in a way that everything is still readable in the end.

I am unsure what you mean with "zoomed in", but you could add the `height` and `width` option to the `axis` environment which will scale the diagram to the stated size. For example, `width=10cm` will scale the diagram to 10cm in width. Alternatively, you could use the `scale` option with a reasonable factor.

In order to grab the coordinate where two paths intersect which you need to correctly position the brace showing the unexplained part of the variance, you can make use of the `intersections` library.

To nicer arrange the labels, you might want to decrease the font size which often helps already. As for the braces, You might want to mirror some of those and change the `aspect` option (and the `pos` option for the label node respectively) in order to shift the label a bit (it should also work without shifting the label here, I added it just in case you need it due to a larger font size):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={X},
        ylabel={Y},
        xmin=0, xmax=10,
        ymin=0, ymax=10,
        grid=both,
        axis lines=middle,
        every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
        font=\small
    ]   
    % Data points
    \addplot+[only marks] coordinates {
        (1, 3.5)
        (2, 5)
        (3, 4)
        (4, 6.3)
        (5, 8)
        (6, 7)
        (7, 9)
        (8, 9.5)
        (9, 12)
        (10, 11)
    };    
    % Regression line
    \addplot[red, domain=0:10, samples=100, name path=Regr] { x + 2 };
    % Vertical line
    \addplot[blue, dashed, name path=Vert] coordinates {
        (5, 8)
        (5, 5.7) 
    } coordinate[pos=0] (Vert top);
    % Mean Line
    \addplot[black, dashed] coordinates{
        (0, 5.7)
        (10, 5.7)   
    } node[below left] {mean};
    % Curly bracket
    \draw[name intersections={of=Regr and Vert}, decorate, decoration={brace, mirror, amplitude=4pt, aspect=0.33}, thick]
        ([xshift=-5pt]Vert top) -- ([xshift=-5pt]intersection-1) 
        node[pos=0.33, left, xshift=-3pt, text width=5em, align=right] {unexplained variance};
    \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Surely the *unexplained* variation is only the part above the regression line?   The part between the mean and the regression line is supposed to be "explained" by the regression model.

Comment: @Thruston You are right ... I was a bit too much focused on positioning the labels ...

Answer (score 3):

Using [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
\tzaxes(13,13)
\tzticks<-2pt,-2pt>(0pt:4pt){2,4,...,12}(0pt:4pt){2,4,...,12}
% mean
\def\regmean{5.7}
\tzfn[dashed,ultra thick]\regmean[12:0]{mean}[ar]
% regression line
\def\regline{\x+2}
\tzfn[red,ultra thick]\regline[0:11]
% data
\tzplot*[blue](1,3.5)
              (2,5)
              (3,4)
              (4,6.3)
              (5,8)
              (6,7)
              (7,9)
              (8,9.5)
              (9,12)
              (10,11) ;
% explained / unexplained variation
\tzcoor(3,4)(Y){$y$}[l]
\tzvXpoint*[red]{regline}(Y)(Y^){$\hat y$}[180](4pt)
\tzvXpoint*[red]{regmean}(Y)(Y-){$\bar y$}[135](4pt)
\tzbrace[thick](Y-)([yshift=1pt]Y^)
        {explained varitaion\\$\hat y-\bar y$}[r=10pt,align=left]
\tzbrace[thick](Y^)(Y)
        {unexplained\\varitaion\\$y-\hat y$}[r=10pt,align=left]
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \tzline[blue](Y-)(Y)
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```